# Reconnecting to SonicMQ if the connection is refused to SonicMQ

Tags: java, jms, sonicmq

I am unable to get connection to SonicMQ may be because of unavailable Producers/Consurmers. In this case is SonicMQ supports reconnecting after some time interval.

Comment: Can you show an example of the your Queue/Topic ConnectionFactory set up?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if producers or consumers are available, you don't directly connect to them or topics or queues; you connect to the SonicMQ broker. Just use the connection factory to handle reconnect, and if you have multiple brokers, configure them like this...the factory handles reconnection on behalf of the client...

```
QueueConnectionFactory factory = 
    QueueConnectionFactory("broker1:2506;broker2:2506");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but may be you can have a look at this link  [Generic Resource Adapter for JMS](https://genericjmsra.java.net/docs/sonic-mq-integration-guide/sonicmq_integration_guide.html). It provide options for defining connection pool, with reconnection.

Answer (score 0):

It's not sonic MQ that may support reconnecting it's your client applications.
If you develop it to provide such feature it will work.